# Subquery Question

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I am trying to provide a stream of favourites to my users, of the people that they follow.

I wish to select all of the current user's followed IDs and then show all of the favourites that matches these IDs.

I've got the following query, but it doesn't have the desired effect.

```
SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_user_id FROM follows WHERE user_id='2');
```

Do I need to use a join or something?

Kind regards,

Luke

Comment: Your query looks ok, what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: are there data ok ? what you get on inner select ?

Comment: if user_id is INT do not use string type in your qury

Comment: Apologies, I just checked the subquery (innser select) and it works. fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very easy

```
SELECT user_id as UserId, blah , blah 
FROM favourites 
WHERE user_id IN ( 
                  SELECT following_user_id 
                  FROM follows 
                  WHERE user_id= UserId
                 );
```